# Output data both to sys.stdout via print and to a time-stamped logger

Tags: python, logging, stream

I have code with a series of print() statements in a Jupyter notebook. I would like to replace each of these outputs with an identical output to stdout and to a time-stamped logger. How is this done? I realize that I can refactor the code to replace print() statements with logger statements, and there are messages discussing that. I want to know whether I can avoid this refactoring step. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is ill-advised, however you may redefine `print` to your own functionality. For example,

```py
def print(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, **kwargs)
    logger.log(*args, ...)
```